# Non partial homomorphic encryption

Tags: encryption, homomorphic-encryption

It seems that AES is non homomorphic. I am seeking a public key non homomorphic encryption that has been proved to be such or at least is accepted as non homomorphic. The internet search leads to those that are homomorphic. Any lead?

Comment: Use any CCA-secure encryption scheme. By definition those cannot have any kind of homomorphism.

Comment: These CCA-secure keyed-homomorphic schemes only allow simple computations on encrypted data, i.e., either adding or multiplying encrypted ciphertexts, but not both operations at the same time. ... Until now, fully homomorphic encryption schemes can only be proven secure against chosen-plaintext attack (CPA).Feb 18, 2016

Comment: I do not want even partial homomorphic encryption

Comment: By definition a CCA secure encryption scheme does not have ANY homomorphism. No matter if full, partial or whatever. Any possible homomorphic evaluation on ciphertexts would immediatelly translate into an attack on the CCA security.

Comment: RSA with proper padding?

Comment: Worth mentioning that you're talking about CCA2, not CCA1 or lunchtime attacks, which can have some homomorphic properties

Answer (score 2):

[mikeazo](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/706) has the answer [in a comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/51431/non-partial-homomorphic-encryption#comment113521_51431):

> RSA with proper padding

So, use RSA (or actually any trap door one way function) with proper padding. For instance: [OAEP padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding). These are designed to achieve [indistinguishability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_indistinguishability), which has also been mentioned in the comments. The padding which uses a hash internally kills all homomorphic properties of the cipher.